# How to add a class to an image using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In my example I have an image of a rocket. My aim is to have it move across the page diagonally, explode, vanish and then when the webpage has been clicked, the rocket will return to its normal state and position.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#rocket').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '+=800px',
        top: '-=600px',
    });
    $('#rocket').hide('explode', {pieces: 25}, 1000);
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#normal').click(function() {
        $('this').addClass('#rocket', 'unlaunched');
    });
});
```

So far the moving, the exploding and the vanishing works. However, the clicking onto the webpage to return the rocket back to normal doesn't. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just remove quots: `$(this).addClass('#rocket', 'unlaunched');`

Comment: if you're just wanting to set the class on "#rocket", you could replace $('this').addClass('#rocket', 'unlaunched'); with $('#rocket').addClass('unlaunched');

Comment: Just a couple of comments, you don't need to use two `$(document).ready()` enclosures. Instead just put everything into one. The jQuery addClass function accepts only one 'string' parameter so if you want to add a class to the rocket you could use `$('#rocket').addClass('unlaunched')`

Comment: @Jackson good call. this helped a lot. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `#` sign. remove this sign from this line `$('this').addClass('rocket', 'unlaunched');`

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rocket').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
          left: '+=800px',
          top: '-=600px'
        });
    $('#rocket').hide('explode', {pieces: 25}, 1000);
  });
  
  
    $('#normal').click(function() {
        $('this').addClass('rocket', 'unlaunched');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just targeting the wrong thing using the this keyword.

Here is how you should add a class to an element in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#normal').click(function() {
        $('#rocket').addClass('unlaunched');
    });
});
```

See my jsfiddle incase it helps you!

https://jsfiddle.net/1k3oxjmh/

Answer (score 0):

In your document ready function you will need to show the rocket again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#normal').click(function() {
        $('#rocket').show();
    });
});
```